# Could not make POST request to add comments to my backend server

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, backend

I am new to `express` and router. When I try to add a comment to the database, the console returned the error (`"Post 400 Bad request" and "Uncaught in Promise"`). I've tried many solutions but it doesn't work. I think it is to do with my routing.

Below is my profilesRouter.js in the backend folder:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

class profilesRouter {
  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }
  routes() {
    router.get("/", this.controller.getAll.bind(this.controller));
    router.get(
      "/:profileId/comments",
      this.controller.getComments.bind(this.controller)
    );
    router.post(
      "/:profileId/comments",
      this.controller.addComment.bind(this.controller)
    );
    return router;
  }
}

module.exports = profilesRouter;
```

Here is my profilesController.js in the backend folder.

```
const BaseController = require("./baseController");

class profilesController extends BaseController {
  constructor(model) {
    super(model);
  }

  async getComments(req, res) {
    const { profileId } = req.params;
    try {
      const comments = await this.models.comment.findByPk(profileId);
      return res.json(comments);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, msg: err });
    }
  }

  async addComment(req, res) {
    try {
      const comment = { ...req.body };
      const newComment = await this.models.comment.create(comment);
      return res.json(newComment);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: true, msg: err });
    }
  }
}

module.exports = profilesController;
```

On the other hand, for my frontend folder:
Here is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Single from "./Single";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [profiles, setprofiles] = useState([]);
  const getInitialData = async () => {
    let initialAPICall = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER}/profiles`
    );
    setprofiles(initialAPICall.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getInitialData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/profiles"
          element={<Card profiles={profiles} />}
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/profiles/:profileIndex"
          element={<Single profiles={profiles} />}
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Upon clicking on individual profiles, it will bring me to Single.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { BACKEND_URL } from "../src/constant";

const Single = ({ profiles }) => {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState();
  const [commentContent, setCommentContent] = useState("");
  const { profileIndex } = useParams();
  const profile = profiles[profileIndex];

  console.log(profile);

  useEffect(() => {
    // If there is a profiles.id, retrieve the profile data
    if (profile.id) {
      axios
        .get(`${BACKEND_URL}/profiles/${profile.id}/comments`)
        .then((response) => {
          setComments(response.data);
        });
    }
    // Only run this effect on change to profiles.id
  }, [profile.id]);

  console.log(profile.id);

  if (!profile) {
    return "No Profile";
  }

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCommentContent(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // Prevent default form redirect on submission
    event.preventDefault();

    // Send request to create new comment in backend
    axios
      .post(
        `${BACKEND_URL}/profiles/${profile.id}/comments`,
        {
          content: commentContent,
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        // Clear form state
        setCommentContent("");

        // Refresh local comment list
        return axios.get(
          `${BACKEND_URL}/profiles/${profile.id}/comments`
        );
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setComments(response.data);
      });
  };

  // Store a new JSX element for each comment
  const commentElements = comments
    ? comments.map((comment) => (
        <ol key={comment.id}>
          {comment.createdAt} | {comment.content}
        </ol>
      ))
    : [];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          // Use textarea to give user more space to type
          as="textarea"
          name="content"
          value={comments}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Single;
```

Data is being stored in profile.json without the comments: `[{"PROFILE_NUMBER": "A123", "NAME": "X", "AGE" : "21", "HOBBY" : "RUN"} , .....]`

I am quite new and not sure how to debug it and push my comments into the database.

Comment: What debugging steps have been taken? This is a bit of a code dump and request for us to debug it, this isn't what stackoverflow is for. Are you certain this is the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce the backend error? See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this method

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {

let { userid, comment } = req.body;

commentModel.create({

    userid: userid,
    comment: comment     

}).then((data) => {
    console.log("data-add", data);
    return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: "Comment added",
        data: data
    })
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: error.message,
        data: []
    })
 })
});
```